# homogenous second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How would one solve the differential equation:

$\dfrac{1}{X}\dfrac{d^2X}{dx^2} = \lambda$

Maybe it is obvious but I don't know.

Comment: ah ok. How do you solve it

Answer (score 1):

You first write the equation like this:

$$X''−\lambda X=0$$

Than you know that the second order differential equation can be solved using a technique that is similar to looking the coefficients of the quadratic equation. So you pick some $\omega $ to act as your coeficient and you write your differental equation now in a form of a quadratic formula like this:

$$\omega^2-\lambda=0$$

Than you solve that quadratic equation which ever way you like and you obtain (in this case) two real solutions, namely $\omega_{1,2}=\sqrt{\lambda},-\sqrt\lambda$ and you now write in the form that is suitable for 2 real solutions:

$X=C_{1}e^{\omega_{1}x}+C_{2}e^{\omega_{2}x}$ and when you input your $\lambda,-\lambda$ you get $$X=C_{1}e^{\sqrt{\lambda}x}+C_{2}e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}x}$$

Rewriting you get:

$$X=C_{1}e^{\sqrt{\lambda}x}+\dfrac {C_{2}}{e^{\sqrt{\lambda}x}}$$

and that is the solution.

You can check that by differentiating $X$ twice and substituting it in your starting differential equation.

Answer (score 0):

As commented above, your equation is a particular case of a [homogeneous second-order linear differential equation with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Second-order_case), of which the general form is
$$
\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2} + a \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} + b y = 0
$$
for real coefficients $a$ and $b$. Here, you have $a = 0$ and $b = - \lambda$. The linked Wikipedia page should help you solve it. In particular, the solutions are very different depending on the sign of the coefficient $\lambda$.